# Scala on Android: Failed resolving MainActivity; interface 540 'Lscala/ScalaObject;'

Tags: android, eclipse, scala

I used this tutorial to get Eclipse, Scala and Android up and running:
http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/androiddevelopment/index.html

I also took the example source code of this webpage (delete MainActivity.java - created MainActivity.scala).

Running the application, I get error messages:

```
01-15 18:14:06.740: I/dalvikvm(27536): Failed resolving Lcom/test/helloworldscala/MainActivity; interface 540 'Lscala/ScalaObject;'
01-15 18:14:06.740: W/dalvikvm(27536): Link of class 'Lcom/test/helloworldscala/MainActivity;' failed
01-15 18:14:06.740: D/AndroidRuntime(27536): Shutting down VM
01-15 18:14:06.740: W/dalvikvm(27536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415fd2a0)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.helloworldscala/com.test.helloworldscala.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.helloworldscala.MainActivity
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.helloworldscala.MainActivity
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
01-15 18:14:06.740: E/AndroidRuntime(27536):    ... 11 more
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: My guessing is that scala-library.jar is not being bundled.

Comment: In Java Build Path I have on the tab "Libararies" "Scala Library [2.9.3-RC1]" and the link to the scala-library.jar is ../adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/391/1/.cp/lib where I can find the jar file.

Comment: I'd try building with `ant`, I've never built android apps with an IDE.

Comment: Okay, I will try it with Ant if there is no other solution, but I hope there is one.

Comment: You probably have you add the scala-library.jar manually, instead of relying on IDE to do that - pure guessing. If it helps I found that using sbt, sbt-android and sbt-eclipse/intellij was far better than IDE builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a nightly build of the Scala-IDE with Scala 2.10., then it works perfectly.